# How to practice cpanel on virtual environment

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, centos

I'm starting my sysadmin education and want to learn OS installations etc. The system I want to learn includes cPanel, but it seems there's no way to actually experiment with cPanel on a virtual environment and/or without paying for a license. Can someone give me advice how I can experiment with learning cPanel installation as part of an installation on virtual environment?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software licensing and acquisition.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cpanel


Answer (score 0):

You can install cPanel and get a time limited trial license. This should give you all the access you need to learn without a huge cost. If that fails look for a VPS vendor that has a cPanel site license and can give you a low cost VPS to play with.

Comment: you also generally cant install cpanel without it running on a publically routable ip address, it generally wont install

Comment: @anthonysomerset, that's what I was wondering about

Comment: your best bet is getting hold of a cheap vps and installing the trial version there